# Bash скрипт проверки текста на сайте

Tags: linux, bash

нужна помощь в решении данного условия.

Написать скрипт или автоматический тест или команду в unix консоли, который проверить, что на странице https://www.youtube.com/ есть текст "Рекомендованные"

Буду очень признателен в решении.

Comment: Начните с чего-нибудь, что вы пробовали уже и что не получается?

Comment: не понимаю как это реализовать((( и в сети не могу найти даже похожий пример чтобы в этом разобраться

Comment: На чистом `bash` это практически невозможно. Зато очень легко с помощью `curl` и утилит работы с XPath. Но даже условие несколько *корявое*. Что значит **текст**? Для SGML языков этот термин требует достаточных уточнений.

Comment: Может сurl и grep?

Comment: Прям очень плохо составленный вопрос.

Comment: @РашенБеарsaystohellMonica, конечно, ещё один пришёл разбирать XML `grep`ом...

Comment: Не разбирать, а искать вхождение подстроки.

Comment: Да, я тоже понимаю что условие кривое и тоже думаю что нужно использовать curl. Сможете помочь таким образом сделать?

Comment: @РашенБеарsaystohellMonica, zOMG! Успехов в дальнейшей жизни! Вопросов более не имею.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С обычным curl это немножко сложно - ютубу он не нравится (но никто не мешает поиграться хедерами). А вот wget - в самый раз

```
wget https://youtube.com/ -O - | grep -q "Рекомендованные" && echo "Да" || echo "Нет"
```

вначале вытягиваем страницу и выводим на консоль. Потом "грепаем". Так как grep выставляет правильный код возврата, то используем типичную комбинацию для вывода ответа.

Comment: Молодец, научился `grep`ом по XMLю: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: А что не так то с грепом по XMLю? Аргументы будут?

Comment: а кто сказал, что выдача страницы - чистый xml?

Comment: Куда катится этот мир?! :-( Надеюсь вы не в Гугле работаете.

Comment: вот вот. Все цитируют один и тот же ответ.

Comment: Хедеры тут ни при чём, просто надо знать как работает инструмент которым пользуетесь... `curl -L https://youtube.com/ | grep -q "Рекомендованные" && echo "Да" || echo "Нет"` По умолчанию курл не ходит по редиректам(301), а вот с глючиком `-L` реагирует и идёт туда куда его послали, то-есть на https://www.youtube.com/

Answer (score 5):

```
curl -L -H "Accept-Language: ru-RU, ru" https://youtube.com/ | grep -q "Рекомендованные" && echo "Да" || echo "Нет"
```

Так надёжнее, а то на аглицком ещё выдаст. Кстати рекомендованных, без куков пользователя, вы не увидите.